# How to integrate and test Google Wallet Feature if you are situated in a country where this application is not available?

Tags: android, rest, google-play-services, google-developers-console, google-wallet

Can you suggest ways by which I can use and test the Google Wallet application to add passes to it programmatically from my Android application? The current limitation that I am facing is, Google Wallet application is not available in the country that I am situated in. Any ideas to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you use the google wallet web API then you can test your pass in Google chrome. you can add the pass in your google acount  see and test it. the only think you can not test is the animation barcode and the rooting barcode. if you are using google wallet SDK then i have no idea. (you can use the web API in andriod instead of the google wallet SDK).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).